# tunnel through one port

Tags: proxy, port, tunnel

I have limited network connection with only few port opened (80,443,...) and I also have server without these limits which is out of limited network.

Is there any way how to tunnel through one port to all other ports? 
I can install whatever I want on my server - Currently there is Ubuntu server 12.

Can you suggest me any solution? If there is any.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'll point you to this question on super user:

- [How can I tunnel all of my network traffic through SSH?](https://superuser.com/questions/62303/how-can-i-tunnel-all-of-my-network-traffic-through-ssh)

The top suggestions are to give [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/) a go and since you are using Linux this would be a good choice.

But also Linux has inbuilt support for this, you can find details using `man ssh`:

```
 The following example would connect client network 10.0.50.0/24 with
 remote network 10.0.99.0/24, provided that the SSH server running on the
 gateway to the remote network, at 192.168.1.15, allows it:

   # ssh -f -w 0:1 192.168.1.15 true
   # ifconfig tun0 10.0.50.1 10.0.99.1 netmask 255.255.255.252
```

The one thing that wasn't mentioned is setting up a VPN, but you can only do that if you have port `1723` open (for PPTP).